# How to patch CVE-2015-0235 (GHOST) on Debian Lenny and Squeeze?

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, debian-lenny, vulnerabilities

There is a right way to patch GHOST on Debian Lenny and Squeeze?

According to this link there are no plans to patch Lenny
https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2015-0235

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, that you must have a source repository set-up in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 7):

Install devscripts

Get the patch for lenny from http://pastebin.com/Hhsut197 (based on the [official glibc patch](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=patch;h=d5dd6189d506068ed11c8bfa1e1e9bffde04decd), removed ChangeLog, NEWS stuff, adapted Makefile for lenny, removed patch #2 for getXXbyYY_r.c)

Run: `apt-get update && apt-get source libc6; apt-get build-dep libc6`

Copy your patch in `glibc-2.7/debian/patches/all`

Add the patch name in `glibc-2.7/debian/patches/series`

Run rebuild (or install devscripts package and run debuild) and you should be done

The idea should be the same for etch. Adapted patch for etch is here: pastebin.com/UXGnJd6A

Squeeze is patched (`libc6-2.11.3-4+deb6u4`) only if you have squeeze-lts repository in your sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main
```

Comment: The patch for lenny doesn't apply. All hunks on `nss/digits_dots.c` fail.

Comment: Michael's procedure worked for me but not the patchfile that was provided; here's the patch that worked for me: http://pastebin.com/N0SSivW6 EDIT: actually, I'm willing to bet that one doesn't work either, due to screwy whitespace issues from cutting and pasting; I'll put it directly here: http://richardhoward.net/lenny-ghost.diff

Comment: Sorry, but can you write de command needed to "debuild" or "rebuild", I don't know if debuild is the correct name or if there is a mistake and the correct command is rebuild. Thanks

Comment: I complete the build using the Michael and rhowardiv indications to update the libc6 packages in debian 5 lenny.
You can see the detailed procedure here:
https://gist.github.com/eduherraiz/b3180f2c405a91a2ef25

Comment: thanks for deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the eglibc patch from Squeeze LTS to build patched Lenny packages:
http://sources.debian.net/data/main/e/eglibc/2.11.3-4+deb6u4/debian/patches/any/cvs-gethostbyname.diff

Put it in glibc-2.7/debian/patches/any and add it to the end of the glibc-2.7/debian/patches/series file. Now build the packages, upgrade your system with them and test your system with the GHOST tool: https://webshare.uchicago.edu/orgs/ITServices/itsec/Downloads/GHOST.c

Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

I've recompiled the glibc-2.7 sources for Debian Lenny including the CVE-2015-0235 patch of Debian Squeeze LTS.

As it takes quite some time to compile these packages you may grab a copy via https://flo.sh/debian-lenny-cve-2015-0235-glibc-patch/

Vulnerability check looks ok, now:
[00:15:26] root@[...]: /usr/src/ghost> ./ghost
not vulnerable

Thank you guys for adding this compact summary on this issue,
-Flo

Answer (score 0):

I was waiting to see if someone would package a lenny glibc .deb like a guy from linux.it did for shell shock.

Finally, I did it myself and managed to apply the original patch from pastebin.com mentioned previously width -l option to patch.

We have also old debian sarge still running, and the same patch could be applied to glibc-2.3.2 with little modification:

http://www.saitis.net/~ndesir/cve-2015-0235-old-debian/sarge/cve-2015-0235.dpatch

and add it to     debian/patches/00list     before running debuild

seems to work well till now.

If you trust me enough, http://www.saitis.net/~ndesir/cve-2015-0235-old-debian/ also contains the .deb for lenny and sarge (intel).